# overload operator [ ] to enable element assignment

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, thrust

I've already overloaded operator [ ] to enable element access.

**definition**

```
double Matrix::operator[ ](const & int i){
     return data[i]; // data[] is a member array: thrust:: device_vector
}
```

**usage**

```
Matrix m = ... // initialize
std::cout << m[3] << std::endl;
```

But now I want to access element by index so that assign new value to it.

**usage**

```
m[3] = 0.;
```

I understand the return value of the operator overload function must be an lvalue. I guess I should return a reference, but not sure how this is done. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Now I changed my definition to double &, but it still complains:

```
 error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

The array refers to a thrust::device_vector, which can be assigned value by index:

```
Thrust::device_vector<double> M(10);
M[3] = 0.;
```

Comment: Please do not keep changing the error. You have presented one, and that was solved. Your question was answered... Open up a new one if you have further. You cannot expect the people trying to help to keep the update with your continuous changing. For that reasoning, this is -1 from me.

Comment: I've posted a new question. Thanks reminding me this!

Comment: Also, this matrix vs. thrust is also confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

`double ....`

with

`double& .....`

Comment: error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue. I returned a thrust::device_vector, which is accessible using indices

Comment: @user2684645, how is the `data` defined and initialized?

Comment: @cpp I asked a new question to avoid multiple questions in one thread. Thanks for answering  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651675/overload-operator-to-access-thrustdevice-vector-in-a-class

Answer (score 0):

change your definition to

```
double& Matrix::operator[ ](const & int i){
     return data[i]; // data[] is a member array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, you should not use reference for an integer argument. It is usually used for complex classes for avoiding the copy. I would also suggest as a side note, to use m_memberVariable unless you use pimpl. This is what you should write:

```
double& Matrix::operator[ ] (const int i) {
     return m_data[i]; // data[] is a member array
}
```

Note, you will need to add the '&' marker also in the class header where the method is declared.

This is all provided you have something like this in the class header:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    double m_data[100];

public:
    double& operator[] (const int i);
};
```

[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/) you can read further details on the subscript operator overloading. [This](http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/references.htm) is another url for learning more about references.

As for a bit of inline explanation why it works like that:

You are trying to use the subscript operator on the left hand for assignment, hence the return value of such an operator overload has to be an l-value as you correctly state it. This is because if you return a value instead of reference, the left hand side in the usage would simply return that value which would evaluate to `x = 0` where replace `x` with a value like `1`. That is why you will get a compiler error in such cases.

Comment: Yes, but why it complains. error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue. array is a thrust::device_vector which is accessible using indices

Comment: My code works fine here. Are you sure you have not made any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you chose to have a pair of operators. One for access:

```
double Matrix::operator[ ] const (const & int i){
     return data[i]; 
}
```

and the other for assigment:

```
double &Matrix::operator[ ](const & int i){
     return data[i]; 
}
```

If you call `[ ] operator` on a const object the first operator is really called. In other cases, both in access as well as assgnement, the second one is called.

You get error:

```
 error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

because `data` is (probably) a local variable. Make it a `Matrix` class private data member if it's not already.

Comment: I think he is just trying to solve the compilation issue at hand rather than asking about optimization.